# Erro ao rodar npm install e start: “npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open”

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Estou recebendo alguns erros ao executar uns arquivos no Node.js. Baixei 2 arquivos no GitHub, e em um tutorial simplesmente fala para executar os seguintes comandos:

> npm install
>
> npm start

O Sistema Operacional é o Windows 10.

Primeiramente eu instalei o Node.JS. Depois abri o PowerShell do windows e andei até a pasta do arquivo.

O comando `dir` retorna as seguintes pastas e arquivos:

```
C:\Users\Evarist\Desktop\yEarn\iearn-finance-master\iearn-finance-master>dir
 O volume na unidade C não tem nome.
 O Número de Série do Volume é 1CE1-A159

 Pasta de C:\Users\Evarist\Desktop\yEarn\iearn-finance-master\iearn-finance-master

06/09/2020  15:28    <DIR>          .
06/09/2020  15:28    <DIR>          ..
03/09/2020  11:45               317 .gitignore
03/09/2020  11:45             1.062 LICENSE
06/09/2020  15:28    <DIR>          node_modules
03/09/2020  11:45         1.474.998 package-lock.json
03/09/2020  11:45             1.860 package.json
03/09/2020  11:45    <DIR>          public
03/09/2020  11:45             2.898 README.md
03/09/2020  11:45    <DIR>          src
               5 arquivo(s)      1.481.135 bytes
               5 pasta(s)    9.335.443.456 bytes disponíveis
```

O comando `npm install` saiu o resultado:

```
   C:\Users\Evarist\Desktop\yEarn\iearn-finance-master\iearn-finance-master>npm install
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Evarist\Desktop\yEarn\iearn-finance-master\iearn-finance-master\node_modules\.staging\bip39-5f8d4250\package.json'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Evarist\Desktop\yEarn\iearn-finance-master\iearn-finance-master\node_modules\.staging\bip39-5f8d4250\index.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Evarist\Desktop\yEarn\iearn-finance-master\iearn-finance-master\node_modules\.staging\hdkey-41e89c69\package.json'
    [.....]
```

Os arquivos que baixei:

https://github.com/iearn-finance/iearn-finance

https://github.com/iearn-finance/itoken

Como resolver isto?

Answer (score 0):

Então, todo o projeto node precisa do package.json. Ele é o responsável por carregar tudo o que teu projeto precisa. Se teu projeto não tiver o packge.json ele não vai conseguir entender de onde ele tem que baixar as bibliotecas, outros dados necessários e afins.

Faz o seguinte, baixa o projeto novamente e dá o npm install

Answer (score -1):

Faz o seguite:

- renomeia a tua pasta para **finances**
- entre dentro da pasta e remove o **node_modules**, o **package.json** e o **package-lock.json**
- em seguida, executa o npm install

Comment: Olá, boa noite. Obrigado por comentar. Infelizmente é o NPM que cria a pasta node_modules, e esta pasta é vazia.
Removi os outros dois arquivos. Segue abaixo o erro no resultado:

Answer (score -1):

Removi o package.json e o package-lock.json. o programa retorna o seguinte erro:

```
C:\Users\Evarist\Desktop\finances\itoken-master\itoken-master>npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Evarist\Desktop\finances\itoken-master\itoken-master\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Evarist\Desktop\finances\itoken-master\itoken-master\package.json'
npm WARN itoken-master No description
npm WARN itoken-master No repository field.
npm WARN itoken-master No README data
npm WARN itoken-master No license field.

up to date in 1.588s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Answer (score -2):

só confere se vc está executando o npm start dentro da pasta correta e verifica se o script é autorizado com o comando Set-ExecutionPolicy e depois executa RemoteSigned